# "deep insights" vs. "keen insights"

Tags: difference, expressions, intensifiers

Is there any difference between the expressions "deep insights" and "keen insights"? In meaning or just in intensity?

Based on the usage examples available to me, "deep" and "keen", both seem to be just intensifiers to "insight".

Comment: A dictionary could tell you the difference between "deep" and "keen".

Comment: You *could* say they're both just "intensifiers". But obviously the "literal" meanings of ***deep*** (essentially, ***profound*** here) and ***keen*** (***sharp-witted, perceptive***) are very different. Some readers will be able to conceptualise those two concepts differently as applied to something like ***insights***, and some won't.

Comment: I myself can get my head around the idea that a ***keen*** insight might typically involve spotting things that aren't so obvious to many people (even though those things might not be "fundamental" to the matter under scrutiny), whereas a ***deep*** insight would more likely be one concerned with ***the basic underlying principles*** governing the subject.

Comment: @Astralbee A link to the corresponding dict entry would be highly appreciated. The dictionaries consulted by me distinguish 3 meanings for "keen": eager, strong, sharp. But for none of those meanings any examples with "insights" are given. So, no way to know if a keen insight is a "strong" (profound) or "sharp" (sharp-witted) one.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet There are many dictionaries online. Questions which can be answered wtih a dictionary are off-topic on this site. If you've researched the dictionary and your question is over your research, please include that in your question and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keen is a synonym for sharp, rather than for deep. "Keen insights" suggests making clear distinctions and solving problems, while "deep insights" suggests seeing past surface matters to the fundamental issues.

"Clear insights" is also used.